# Checking power of two for unsigned integer

Tags: binary, unsigned

**Consider the following code snippet for checking whether a number is power of 2 or not.**

```
*function to check if x is power of 2*

bool isPowerOfTwo (unsigned int x) 
{ 
  return (!(x&(x-1))); 
}
```

***What is wrong with above function?***

1. It does reverse of what is required.
2. It works perfectly fine for all values of x.
3. It does not work for x = 0
4. It does not work for x = 1

The correct answer is option **3.** but I cannot understand how ?
Shouldn't it be option **4.** because **1&(1-1)=0** and **!0 = true** but 1 is not a power of two hence the function doesn't work for x=1

Edit: sorry I didn't realise 2^0 would be 1.
Got the answer, thanks

Comment: I'm assuming `&` is the logical AND-operation so why would `1 & 1 = 0`? `x AND x = x`.

Comment: Did you meant to write `1&(1-1)=0`?

Comment: "... 1 is not a power of two ...".  What is the value of 2 raised to the power 0 ?

Comment: Yes I did. Let me edit the question

Comment: Damn, I'm so sorry I didn't realise. I was screwed up in the head. Thanks a lot